# A custom layer in Keras returns NaN as a gradient. What are some potential issues causing this?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gradient, tensorflow2.0

I work on a project where we try to reconstruct a 2D image from geometric primitives. To this end, I have developped a custom Keras layer which outputs an image of a cone given its geometric charcteristics.

Its input is a tensor of shape batch_size * 5, where the five numbers are the xy coordinates of the apex of the cone, the xy coordinates of the unit vector describing the axis of the cone, and the angle at the top of the cone.

The goal is to use this layer as a non-trainable decoder in an encoder-decoder architecture. We would then feed the neural network with cone images. The expected behavior is that the neural network should then learn a latent representation similar to the one described above.

When I incorporate this layer in a larger network and try to optimize it, invariably some weights end up being updated to NaN. This happens even with a network as simple as a two-neuron hidden layer without activation functions.

I have thoroughly tested my layer. Its output is consistent with what I expect it to be. I can't find any trivial mistake in the implementation (but you should be warned I am still fairly new to tensorflow and keras). I have narrowed the issue down to the automatic differentiation of the layer.

The gradient appears to be equal either to 0.0 or to NaN. My understanding is that some numerical instability causes the gradient to diverge.

The question is twofold :

- what is the underlying cause here ?
- how can I fix it ?

Below is a minimum working example showing how the gradient winds up equal to 0.0 or NaN for specific values.

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy.random as rnd

class Cones(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super(Cones, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        coordinates = np.zeros((self.output_dim, self.output_dim, 2))
        for i in range(self.output_dim):
           for j in range(self.output_dim):
              coordinates[i,j,:] = np.array([i,j])

        coordinates = K.constant(coordinates)
        self.coordinates = tf.Variable(initial_value=coordinates, trainable=False)
        self.smooth_sign_width = tf.Variable(initial_value=output_dim, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
        self.grid_width = tf.Variable(initial_value=output_dim, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)


    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(Cones, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        center = self.grid_width*x[:,:2]
        center = K.expand_dims(center, axis=1)
        center = K.expand_dims(center, axis=1)

        direction = x[:,2:4]
        direction = K.expand_dims(direction,1)
        direction = K.expand_dims(direction,1)
        direction = K.l2_normalize(direction, axis=-1)

        aperture = np.pi*x[:,4:]
        aperture = K.expand_dims(aperture)

        u = self.coordinates - center
        u = K.l2_normalize(u, axis=-1)

        angle = K.sum(u*direction, axis=-1)
        angle = K.minimum(angle, K.ones_like(angle))
        angle = K.maximum(angle, -K.ones_like(angle))

        angle = tf.math.acos(angle)


        output = self.smooth_sign(aperture-angle)

        output = K.expand_dims(output, -1)
        return output

    def smooth_sign(self, x):
        return tf.math.sigmoid(self.smooth_sign_width*x)


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim, self.output_dim, 1)

geom = K.constant([[0.34015268, 0.31530404, -0.6827047, 0.7306944, 0.8521315]])
image = Cones(Nx)(geom)

x0 = geom
y0 = image

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(x0)
    cone = Cones(Nx)(x0)
    error = cone-y0
    error_squared = error*error
    mse = tf.math.reduce_mean(error_squared)

print(t.gradient(mse, x0))

geom = K.constant([[0.742021, 0.25431857, 0.90899783, 0.4168009, 0.58542883]])
image = Cones(Nx)(geom)

x0 = geom
y0 = image

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(x0)
    cone = Cones(Nx)(x0)
    error = cone-y0
    error_squared = error*error
    mse = tf.math.reduce_mean(error_squared)

print(t.gradient(mse, x0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I answer my own question and leave it there in case it may help someone in the future. I don't know if this is the generally agreed upon etiquette at StackOverflow.

By commenting the successive steps of the call function, I found out that the issue was with `tf.math.acos`. In the code above, I already had an issue with `acos` which led me to clip the values I fed it between -1 and 1. Numerical issues meant that sometimes the dot product of two unit vectors fell outside of this range, where `acos` is defined. However, by doing so, I ended up evaluating `acos`at 1 and -1, where it is not differentiable, hence the NaN in the gradient.

To fix this issue, I first changed my method to calculate the angle between two vectors, using [this scicomp stack exchange answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27689/numerically-stable-way-of-computing-angles-between-vectors). Then, I clipped the range on which I perform the computation to avoid the non differentiability of `sqrt` at 0. More precisely, whenever I have `c > 1.95`, I round the angle to `pi`, and whenever I have `c < 0.05`, I round the angle to 0.